# How to click on Menu items with PostMessage/SendMessage User32

Tags: c#, sendmessage, postmessage, user32

Hello i have Windows aplication,i need to click on One on Menu/Tabs  items.I can find the Menu with all options,files,help.... tabs ,but i can't find the way how to get to my item.

I can't send picture of my aplication,but i will send the same example/logic with IE where i need to Click on Greek(IOS).

1.I need to click on View

2.Hover Encoding

3.Hover More

and 4. Click Greek(IOS).

[image]

I can find the all bar Menu with File,Edut,View,Tools,Help

```
intWhdr = FindWindow(Step1Window.Class, Step1Window.Name);//Program 
currChild = FindWindowEx(intWhdr, 0, "WindowsForms10.Window.", "mainMenu");//Menu
```

here i have my Main menu , here i stuck i can't find the way to press on menu item(like in Ie example)View menu.
I don't even need the hover action i can user SendMessage DownArrow and RightArrow to get to my item, but i neeed to click on View first.

Any ideas how to click on View menu form Menu bar?with SendMessage/PostMessage

**UPDATE**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long research and with help of  **dvasanth**,i find the salution

1.Yon need to find WM_LBUTTONUP/DOWN **NOT WM_SETCURSOR** like in img,than open the properties and find wParam and lParam

2.Change format 011C16A8 just by adding 0x+lParam/wParam

**Ex: 011C16A8 = 0x011C16A8**

**EX: 00000001= 0x01**

**EX: 00000012=0x12**

I think i get an idea....

In my case i find in properties :

WM_LBUTTONUP

```
lParam=00000001
wParam=000C0348
```

WM_LBUTTONDOWN

```
lParam=00000000
wParam=000C0348
```

sow after edit they look like this:

WM_LBUTTONUP

```
lParam=0x01
wParam=0x000C0348
```

WM_LBUTTONDOWN

```
 lParam=0x00
 wParam=0x000C0348
```

3.Just insert this to your code.

My code that worked:

```
intRes1 = PostMessage(currChild, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0x01, 0x000C0348);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
intRes1 = PostMessage(currChild, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0x00, 0x000C0348);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use spy++ to track all the events delivered to the menu bar & then try re-sending the message from your program.

Comment: I found this event(see Update),i think that hi is pressing the Menu item,but i don't realy know how to use it in code.

Comment: Invoke sendmessage API with the message, lparam, wparam & handle to the window.

Comment: I tried but wParam =011C16A8 and handle=011C16A8  is  not IntPtr or Int  sow i can't use  sendmessage,i don't know the sendmessage that will work with 011C16A8 (i event don't know what format is that)